# drag and drop from one dhtmlxTree to another

Tags: tree, drag-and-drop, dhtmlx

I am trying to drag and drop from one dhtmlxTree to another. I want to drag only the selected item not the siblings of the selected item, How can I handle it?
I have already the next:

```
tree = new dhtmlXTreeObject("tree_1","100%","100%",0);
tree.setImagePath("codebase/imgs/dhxtree_skyblue/");
tree.enableDragAndDrop(true);      //any
tree.loadXML("tree_dnd.xml");
tree.attachEvent("onDrag", function(sId, tId, id, sObject, tObject){
    return false
});
tree2 = new dhtmlXTreeObject("tree_2","100%","100%",0);
tree2.setImagePath("codebase/imgs/dhxtree_skyblue/");
tree2.enableDragAndDrop(true);
tree2.loadXML("tree_dnd.xml");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
tree2.attachEvent("onDrag", function(sId, tId, id, sObject, tObject){
    if (sObject == tObject){
        return false;
    }
    else {
        tree2.insertNewItem(tId, id+"_new", tree.getItemText(sId));
        return false;
    }
});
```